# sql query group by erroring

Tags: sql

The query which works looks like this :

```
SELECT     d.dosno, 
CAST(SUM(k.uur) + SUM(k.minuut) / 60 AS VARCHAR(4)) + 'u ' + 
CAST(SUM(k.minuut) % 60 AS VARCHAR     (2)) + 'm' AS derivedColumn
FROM         dbo.kbpres AS k INNER JOIN
dbo.doss AS d ON k.ino = d.ino
WHERE     (d.dosno = '93690')
GROUP BY d.dosno
```

I would like to add this :

```
(SUM(k.uur) * 60 + SUM(k.minuut)) * k.prijs AS TotalCost
```

but then I should add k.prijs to the groupby according to the error I get, but I don't want this because then I get 21 results instead of just one totalresult.

example :

```
dosno    uur    minuut  prijs

93690    0      5       2

93690    1      0       1

93690    0      10      2

93690    0      5       5
```

result I need is :

```
93690    1:20     800
```

Comment: But if each record has its own distinct `k.prijs` value, how does it know which one to multiple the sums by?

Comment: that is my problem indeed. But it should do that  :)

Comment: Please provide some sample input values and the expected results.

Comment: @Nick_BE, surely the total cost should be (5*2 + 60*1 + 10*2 + 5*5) = 115, not (5+60+10+5)*(2+1+2+5)=800 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to add:

```
SUM((k.uur * 60 + k.minuut) * k.prijs) AS TotalCost
```

- to your query - this will derive the cost for each row and then sum those costs.

EDIT: to sum prijs only where soort is K, add:

```
SUM(case k.soort when 'K' then k.prijs end) AS FACKOSTEN
```

- to the existing query.

Comment: Is there a possibility to add this as well to my queryresult :
    SELECT     SUM(dbo.kbpres.prijs) AS FACKOSTEN
FROM         dbo.kbpres INNER JOIN
                      dbo.doss ON dbo.kbpres.ino = dbo.doss.ino
WHERE     (dbo.doss.dosno = '93690') AND (dbo.kbpres.soort = 'K')

Answer (score 0):

When you `GROUP`, you are consolidating rows based on field values.

If you don't aggregate or `GROUP` a field, the query engine doesn't know which row to choose.  You need to either `GROUP BY` that field, or decide how to select **which** value of `prijs` to use.

There are apparently 21 corresponding values.

If you give more info on what you are trying to accomplish you will get a better answer.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: @JonH - please feel free to flag it then.

Comment: It's not abusive - its not correct, no need to flag I just downvoted and expressed a comment.

Comment: @JonH - That's your prerogative.  I do appreciate you being so mature about this, though!

Comment: It suits your comments from earlier - to read the question FIRST and then provide an answer.  Please take a gander at the FAQ for the definition of what is a real answer vs that of a comment.

Comment: Actually OP edited the question after this was posted.  I'm sorry if you took that personally, it wasn't targeted at you individually.  I am quick to DV, but I also check back and remove them if the answer is updated.  I also leave a comment about WHY the majority of the time.  I'm not trying to be a jerk, just to improve content on the site and point out what is incorrect.

Comment: Flag it if you must: Matthew 7:5

Answer (score 0):

If column prijs is same for all 21 values, then if you do

```
(SUM(k.uur) * 60 + SUM(k.minuut)) * MAX(k.prijs) AS TotalCost
```

Then I it would give the desired results.

Comment: But it's not since he already said if he adds that to the `GROUP BY` it expands to 21 rows

Comment: If he use k.prijs in an aggregate function, then no need to add this to group by.

Comment: But it won't be the same for all 21 is what I'm saying.